# Hot deploy of code changes in dependent maven project in Netbeans to tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I have a maven multimodule project. One of the modules contains some core functionality, which is used in the other modules.

When "Build with Dependencies" is executed on one of the modules, that uses the core module, that core module gets also builded.

The other modules are war projects, the core module is a jar-project.

If I debug one of the war projects, it gets deployed to the tomcat and codechanges are automatically deployed to tomcat.

I am using NetBeans 7.4, Tomcat 7.0.50, JDK 1.7.0_51 on Windows 8.

But if I change code in the core-module (jar), these code changes aren´t detected, not builded and also not deployed.
Is it possible to hot deploy such code changes in the core module to the running tomcat debug session?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the deployment actions to pom.xml, like the following:

```
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.6</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <configuration>
                   <target>
                       <unzip src="target/youwarfile.war" dest="/opt/tomcat/webapps/youwar"/>
                   </target>
               </configuration>
               <goals>
                   <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Then the war file will be deployed at "package" stage, Please modify it according to your needs. And ensure to comment out upon release.